# How to access Elasticsearch from other network ? <my static public ip address>:9200

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, remote-access, firewall, portforwarding

I have my Elasticsearch running on my windows 10 server. **I want to access it with < my static public ip address >:9200**

> I can access my elasticsearch from the server with:
>
> - `localhost:9200`
>   `127.0.0.1:9200`
>   `<my ipv4 address from ipconfig>:9200`

> I can access my elasticsearch from the other device connected to same network as server:
>
> - `<my ipv4 address from ipconfig>:9200`

> ***But i cannot access it with outside of network with:***
>
> - ***`<my static public ip address>:9200`***

> I have already created inbound port rule for 9200 in firewall settings.
> And my network settings in elasticsearch.yml
>
> ```
> http.port: 9200
> network.host: 0.0.0.0
> transport.tcp.port: 9300
> discovery.type: single-node
> discovery.seed_hosts: ["0.0.0.0", "[::1]"]
> network.bind_host: 0.0.0.0
> ```

Please help me ?

Note: I have static public ip address and i found my public ip address from `https://whatismyipaddress.com/`

Comment: If it is allowed in your operating system firewall, then you probably have a firewall device blocking the traffic, could be that your ISP is blocking or the SecInfo team if you are in an office, you need to check that. Elastic configuration is correct, your problem is network related.

Comment: it seems that there is network problem. check with telnet or nmap on 9200 from outside.

Comment: I know problem is with network related. Can anyone give me proper solution to solve this? I am not in office and firewall inbound rule is allowed on 9200.

Answer (score 0):

**I have resolved my issue.**
Everything was good, i just allowed incoming connection on port 9200 in AWS ec2 console. Now it's working. Thank you.

> Now i can access it with `<my static public ip address>:9200`